# Writing to csv split text because of double quotes

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write list to csv but when there is a double quote in the string, it splits the text to another cell. Is there a way to keep it in one cell without removing the double quotes?

My list

```
alst = [['John', 'Smith', 'Google, and Samsung'],['John', 'Smith', '"Google", and "Samsung"'],['John', 'Smith', 'Google ", and Samsung']]

output = open('output.csv', 'w')
output.write('first, last, desc\n')
for item in alst:
    output.write('"{0}","{1}","{2}"\n'.format(item[0], item[1], item[2]))
output.close()
```

Output file in excel

```
first | last  | desc                  | (Blank) 
John  | Smith | Google, and Samsung   
John  | Smith | Google"               |  and "Samsung""
John  | Smith | Google                |  and Samsung"
```

What I am trying to get

```
first | last  | desc                 
John  | Smith | Google, and Samsung   
John  | Smith | "Google", and "Samsung" 
John  | Smith | Google ", and Samsung
```

Just one double quote in the string and it splits on comma. How do I prevent this? Do I need to process the list? I still want to keep the double quotes in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Use `csv.writer()` instead and simply pass your lists to the writer.

```
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    writer.writerow(['First', 'Last', 'Desc'])
    writer.writerows(alst)
```

Comment: Is there any way I can fix this without using csv package?

Comment: More than likely yes. However the `csv` library is built-in and purpose built for this exact reason. Any reason you do not wish to use it?

Comment: I am trying to do a project with no import function it but for some reason I can't get this part to output correctly.

Comment: @Hal unless there is a restriction on a project to do this without an import, honestly just use `csv`. You have issues here with a comma located in a text entry, so you would need to find a way to ignore that or define a different delimiter, then make the CSV file accept that delimiter.